# BCrypt obtain symmetric key from BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE

Tags: ssl, winapi, encryption, wireshark, cng

Hence given a `BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE` (Lets say from the **BCryptEncrypt** function) is it possible to obtain the 'Master secret' or the 'SymmetricKey' to see SSL stream on wireshark un encrypted?

Comment: Perhaps better suited for Security SE, because hardly programming related?

Comment: just for future reference, what is Security SE?

and eventually i figured it out